# Update a Table View Cell from two different view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to IOS and i was just working on `UITableView`. I want to populate data in table view from two different View Controllers. I want to update `cell.textLabel.text` from View Controller say `viewController1` and `cell.detailTextLabel.text` from another View Controller say `viewController2`.

I have a barbutton at the top right of the `tableView` and clicking on which it navigates to View Controller A. I have a text label in View Controller A and it returns what ever user has entered to tableView. 
When i click the cell, it navigates to View Controller B. I also have a text label in View Controller B.

Here is my `tableView` datasource method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Names *namesToDisplay = [self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = namesToDisplay.firstName;
    return cell;

}
```

where `Names` is a model class of `NSObject` and lists is an `NSArray` in `tableView`.

It works fine if I update `cell.textlabel.text` and `cell.detailtextlable.text` from a single View Controller either View Controller1 or View Controller2.

I can get data from `viewController2` but where should I have `cell.detailTextLabel.text` ?

Comment: have you solved this problem now? was the answer helpfull? please comment if not or vote/accept if yes ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. coding conventions... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java is a good orientation.
2. It seems like simple parameter handling. You can share the information between the views in the init process.

i.e.

```
// your details view (vc2) header
@class Names;

@interface MyDetailsViewController
{
    Names *names;
    // some variable declaration here
}
// maybe some properties...

- (id)initWithObject:(Names *)p_names;
// ...

@end
```

...

```
// your details view (vc2) main
- (id)initWithObject:(Names *)p_names
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        names = p_names; // so you have the data when the tableView is loading
    }
}
```

...

```
// your main view (vc1)
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Names *namesToDisplay = [self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    MyDetailsViewController *viewController2 = [[MyDetailsViewController alloc] initWithObject:namesToDisplay];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
}
```

if there are further problems, please give some more information where exactly ;)